# Using Matplotlib to Plot Sympy Implicit Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I have an implicit function, say `x**2 - y = 0` (to simplify), of which I want to obtain a plot for a certain range of `x` values.

`sympy.plot_implicit` usually gives some spreading of the lines that I am not happy with.

I would like to have access to the plotted values, and so `pyplot.plot` is preferable to me. Usually I use the following piece of code to get my explicit Sympy functions plotted, but I am unsure how to use something similar for `exp = sym.Eq(x**2 - y, 0)`. Does anyone have a solutions for this?

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x, y = sym.symbols('x y', nonnegative=True)
exp = x**2

# Plot using a numpy-ready function
x_arr = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
exp_func = sym.lambdify(x, exp, 'numpy')
exp_arr = exp_func(x_arr)

plt.plot(x_arr, exp_arr)
```

PS: my real expression is `b_sim` (see below) and I want the plot for the equation **b_sim = -1**. With `sym.plot_implicit(b_sim + 1, (n,0.225,1.5), (h, -1.1, 1.1))` one can see the lines spreading I dislike. Following Oscar Benjami's tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279077/i-have-plotted-an-implicit-function-using-sympy-however-the-plot-doesnt-seem), I attempted the following piece of code that is giving an error for `roots`.

```
from sympy import *

h, nu = symbols('h nu', nonnegative=True) 
b_sim = 1.0*cos(pi*sqrt(1 - h)/(2*nu))*cos(pi*sqrt(h + 1)/(2*nu)) - 1.0*sin(pi*sqrt(1 - h)/(2*nu))*sin(pi*sqrt(h + 1)/(2*nu))/sqrt(1 - h**2)

eq = Eq(b_sim + 1, 0) 
sols = roots(eq, h) 
sym.plot(*sols, (nu, 0.225, 1.5), ylim=(-1.1, 1.1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line spread of `plot_implicit` is caused by the adaptive algorithm. If you set the option `adaptive=False` the plotting module would use a meshgrid approach. However, due to the implementation, the figure is likely not going to be good (too much "segmentation").

This is how you can do it with Numpy and Matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

expr = eq.rewrite(Add)
f = lambdify([nu, h], expr)
n = 2000j
nnu, hh = np.mgrid[0.225:1.5:n, -1.1:1.1:n]
res = f(nnu, hh)

plt.figure()
cmap = ListedColormap(["tab:blue", "tab:blue"])
plt.contour(nnu, hh, res, levels=[0], cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To have access to the plotted values of a sympy function plot, in this case the coordinates of `lines2d` plot, is simple.

Here is the code that plots the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import symbols
import numpy as np
import sympy

x, y = symbols('x y', nonnegative=True)
exp = x**2

# Plot using a numpy-ready function
x_arr = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10)  #small number for demo
exp_func = sympy.lambdify(x, exp, 'numpy')
exp_arr = exp_func(x_arr)

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
lines2d = plt.plot(x_arr, exp_arr)
```

[image: parabola1]

In the code above, `lines2d` is a list of line2d objects. To get the coordinates from the 1st (only one in this case), do this:

```
xys = lines2d[0].get_xydata()
```

And you can use it to plot with this code:-

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(xys[:,0], xys[:,1])
```

Comment: This code was given in the problem statement as applicable to an explicit function y = x^2. In that case the points plotted are simply (x_arr, exp_arr). 
The question is how to adapt this piece of code for an implicit function x^2 - y = 0 (assume in the real world you cannot isolate y on the l.h.s.).